# Windows 10 64bit on Packard Bell LJ61 laptop

Tags: windows, boot

Since upgrading to Windows 10 I have a problem with start up, after a few seconds with no beeps the whole system freezes on booting. a hard power off then back on allows my computer to start. This is consistent, it happens every time.  if I use the computer and then power off without going through the shut down process my computer will start normally.  I'm guessing Windows is saving something during shut down which is required during start up but during shut down is getting corrupted - any ideas anybody?

Comment: Sounds like a [fast startup problem](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)? Tip: cmd (admin): `powercfg /hibernate off` Also check your HDD for consistency and possible errors (be it physical damage or corrupted ntfs). Alot of people will also recommend to do `sfc /scannow` but first try what I suggested. SFC can't always help and can revert some stuff to something you don't want to if you modded your system so try it as a last resort.